# Where on the web are Google Apps Script Cache Service keys saved?

Tags: caching, google-apps-script

The title speaks for itself. I have an application in which I need to store a password, but it must not be accessed by any user of the script, not even the developers of the application.

It is generated by the script and stored in the [Script's Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache). I would like to know where on the web these keys are stored and if I can guarantee that no user of my application, not even it's developers, will have access to this key during the storage period until the key expires.

I didn't find anything in the documentation to tell me that.

Comment: Instead of storing the password store a one way hash instead. [Enum Digest Algorithm](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/digest-algorithm)

Comment: It is actually an encryption key used during the process, so I need it to encrypt and decrypt the data. Would it be possible for me to use hash in this sense?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I probably wouldn't have answered the question had I known that.  That's why it's better to ask the question that you really want to know the answer to.

Comment: Yes, my question was to know the location of the keys, not how they should be stored.

Answer (score 0):

getUserCache() will store to the user's private settings.

[This page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service) seems to explain a bit better. The user cache is private and only accessible to that user. Script cache is public.

> getUserCache()
> Gets the cache instance scoped to the current user and script. User caches are specific to the current user of the script. Use these to store script information that is specific to the current user.

[This](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2011/11/caching-in-cloud-with-google-script.html) was also interesting.

Comment: Yes I understand. The point is that I need users to have access to this encryption key, but only from the application. They cannot know what it is. Neither are the developers. In my script I have stored it in the script cache and I can't find it anywhere (which is desirable), but I want to make sure that I can't really find it in any configuration in the script (as the script properties are shown) or by other way.